# Phishing and Spam

Tags: spam, phishing

i created a small application that sends email to my users, however when i upload it to my server it get's deleted because of the anti-virus anyone can tell me how i can prevent that? i tried to look for the anti-virus configuration and i did not know how!

```
My server is Linux Red Hat, and when it get deleted a popup comes that the script is a PHP-MAILER-7
```

Also, when i send emails using this application, they arrive in JUNK and considered as spam from hotmail, any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the methods that i use to bypass the anti-virus is encrypting my php codes.
You can look at this references:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
```

In other hand, the emails arrive to JUNK, it depends on a lot of things, for example the IP of the server, your message, the sender email...etc so you need to make sure first that your server can send to inbox after that check the letters and other things.